# Invisble Image in DataGrid DataTemplate

Tags: wpf, image, xaml, datagrid, datatrigger

I'm struggling with this like about 2 Days and can't get an answer or solution to my problem.
I'm using C# WPF and my prob is here:

I have a Datagrid which ItemsSource gets binded. Every TextColumn is displaying its value properly. The DataTemplateColumns which contains a picture or a button does not show its value as long i do not enter that Cell. I want to have my DataGrid Read-Only and get the pictures displayed at once and not by clicking in the cell. But they only shows if you click into the cell. I already tried different Image formats (png,bmp,jpg)

So whats the problem with that DataGrid?

Here is the XAML part with the DataTemplaceColumn:

```
<DataGrid AlternatingRowBackground="Gainsboro"
              AlternationCount="2"
              AutoGenerateColumns="False"
              Height="200"
              HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
              ItemsSource="{Binding}"
              Name="DgMain" 
              VerticalAlignment="Top" 
              Width="778" 
              CanUserReorderColumns="False" 
              CanUserResizeColumns="False" 
              CanUserResizeRows="False" 
              CanUserSortColumns="True"
              IsReadOnly="True">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Pic">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Image x:Name="ImgDgMainPic"></Image>
                        <DataTemplate.Triggers>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding pic}" Value="pic1">
                                <Setter TargetName="ImgDgMainPic" Property="Source" Value="Images\picture1.png"/>
                            </DataTrigger>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding pic}" Value="pic2">
                                <Setter TargetName="ImgDgMainPic" Property="Source" Value="Images\picture2.png"/>
                            </DataTrigger>
                        </DataTemplate.Triggers>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

The Value which the DataTriger binds is string which contains "pic1" or "pic2" as you can see.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using `CellEditingTemplate`, you should use `CellTemplate` -

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
   ......              
</DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
```

CellEditingTemplate is shown once you double click on the cell to make it editable. whereas CellTemplate is what you are looking for.